# GIT change between branches

Tags: php, git

I am in a branch that created from the development of "functions / roles"

He made a series of changes and modified the files:
- RoleService.php
- app.php

It turns out that through my sales to make a review and what I want is to do a branch since its development,
Make the changes, upload them, and close the hotfix.

Because changing the branch "functions / roles" to "develop" tells me that I have to take a step in these files.
Since switching to develop says these two previous files are modified.

My question is ... can I not move from one branch to another without putting these files on stage? If I signed as I have to do it for orders.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try to use **git stash** and than if you want to go back to your changes just type **git stash pop**